# Grails flush: true inside Domain.withTransaction {} closure

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

[This](http://desmontandojava.blogspot.com/2013/08/grails-pitfalls-dont-do-flushtrue-when.html) article says the following:

```
Product.withTransaction{
    product.status = "ACTIVE"
    product.save(flush:true) //without this line the total number will be all of them but this one
    Product.countByStatus("ACTIVE")
}
```

The unclear part is the following comment:

> without this line the total number will be all of them but this one

and the explanation in the article right after the above code:

> In the previous code without forcing flush:true we would have been omitting the product we were saving in our transaction.

As per my understanding, if we call `product.save()`(without flush) the `product` instance should be attached to Hibernate session, becoming a `persistent` entity, which should be included in the number returned by `Product.countByStatus("ACTIVE")` as the transaction is same where we have saved the product and hibernate session contains the info of that saved product even if the instruction is not flushed to database.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the DB-session is flushed after the whole transaction block ( either with `withTransaction{}`, `withSession{}` or declarative demarcation) is finished.

`flush:true` makes the session be flushed **immediately**. That means that if you call `product.save()` the `count*()` method returns data BEFORE the session was flushed into the DB. The same behaviour you would get, if you call `count*()` after the transaction:

```
Product.withTransaction{
    product.status = "ACTIVE"
    product.save()
}
// here the TX shouldv'e been committed already
Product.countByStatus("ACTIVE")
```

Comment: agree that in my scenario if we omit the `flush:true` then `count*()` method will return before the session is flushed, but in my understanding the `count*()` method should see that session contains a product with status= "ACTIVE" and should include that product in returned result as well even if the session is not flushed to db yet. In other words the `count*()` query should not check only the records that are already flushed to db but also the content of session and return merged results from both sources. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: yes, you are wrong :) the objects in session are used on id basis. They are needed mostly to optimize reference resolution, like `a.b.c` so that referenced intsances are loaded only once into a session. That's why `count*()`-like methods can not use session to `merge` results

Comment: oh, I see. Any useful resource / documentation on when any subsequent query in the same transaction will or will not take into account both resources(db and non-flushed session data) ?

Comment: "Any useful resource / documentation on when any subsequent query in the same transaction will or will not take into account both resources(db and non-flushed session data) ?" - There are a number of factors here.  Some of the behavior will depend on things like what transaction isolation level you are using as well as what type of datastore.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I was asking about subsequent query in the same transaction, like  `count*()` method in my example after calling `product.save()`(without flushing), in that case transaction isolation level doesn't matter. Need to understand what kind of queries in the same transaction can or cannot take into account unflushed session data as well in returned result

Comment: "Need to understand what kind of queries in the same transaction can or cannot take into account unflushed session data as well in returned result " - Are you using Hibernate?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm using GORM, which uses Hibernate under the hood

Comment: @SurenAznauryan it's not neccessarily true

Comment: @JeffScottBrown in my case it is Hibernate under the hood

Comment: "I'm using GORM, which uses Hibernate under the hood" - Just FYI... We have a number of GORM implementations which do not use Hibernate including MongoDB, Neo4J, Cassandra and others.  More info at http://gorm.grails.org/.